# C error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Alright, so from what I've seen, it seems these errors usually show up whenever there's a semicolon missing, or a misplaced curly-brace or something of that nature. I'm surely just missing it somehow, but I'm not able to find where the error is, or if it is due to an error of that sort. This error in pointing toward line 235, so the end of the last function.

This is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define MAX 100

void display_menu();
int check_option(int option);
int check_size(int size);
void initialize_2Darray(int x[][MAX], int size);
void print_2Darray(int x[][MAX], int size);
void initialize_1Darray(int y[], int size);
void print_1Darray(int y[], int size);
int search_min(int x[][MAX], int r, int c, int size);
int count_match(int x[][MAX], int y[], int size, int r);
int closest_row(int x[][MAX], int y[], int size);
void sort_1Darray(int y[], int size);
void sort_2Darray(int x[][MAX], int size);

int main()
{
        int size, r, c, option;
        int exit = 0; //exits program when = 1
        int x[MAX][MAX], y[MAX];
        srand(time(NULL));
        printf("Enter the size: ");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        while(check_size(size) == 0) {
                printf("\nInvalid input, enter the size of the array again: ");
                scanf("%d", &size);
        }
        while(exit != 6) {
            initialize_2Darray(x, size);
            initialize_1Darray(y, size);
            display_menu();
            scanf("%d", &option);
            while(check_option(option) == 0) {
                printf("Invalid option, enter again: ");
                scanf("%d", &option);
            }
            //Search Min Operation
            if(option == 1) {
                print_2Darray(x, size);
                printf("Enter the row: ");
                scanf("%d", &r);
                printf("\nEnter the col: ");
                scanf("%d", &c);
                printf("The smallest number present in row %d and col %d is %d", r, c, search_min(x, r, c, size));
            }
            //Count Matches Op.
            else if(option == 2) {
                printf("Count Matches Operation\n\n2D array\n");
                print_2Darray(x, size);
                printf("\n1D array\n");
                print_1Darray(y, size);
                printf("\nEnter the row: ");
                scanf("%d", &r);
                if(count_match(x, y, size, r) > 0)
                        printf("There are %d matches from 1D array present in 2D array", count_match(x, y, size, r));
                else
                        printf("There are no numbers from 1D array present in 2D array");
            }
            //Closest Row Op.
            else if(option == 3) {
                printf("\nClosest Row Operation\n\n2D array\n");
                print_2Darray(x, size);
                printf("\n1D array\n");
                print_1Darray(y, size);
                printf("Row closest to the 1D array is row %d", closest_row(x, y, size));
            }
            //Sort 1D Array Op.
            else if(option == 4) {
                printf("Sort 1D Array Operation\n\n1D Array before sorting:\n");
                print_1Darray(y, size);
                sort_1Darray(y, size);
                printf("\n\n1D Array after sorting:\n");
                print_1Darray(y, size);
            }
            //Sort 2D Array Op.
            else if(option == 5) {
                printf("\nSort 2D Array Option\n\n2D Array before sorting:\n");
                print_2Darray(x, size);
                sort_2Darray(x, size);
                printf("\n\n2D Array after sorting:\n");
                print_2Darray(x, size);
            }
            //Exit
            else if(option == 6)
                exit = 6;
        }
        return 0;
}

void display_menu()
{
        printf("\nArray operations, your options are:\n\n1: Search Min\n2: Count Matches\n3: Closest Row\n4: Sort 1D Array\n5: Sort 2D Array\n6: Exit\nEnter the operation you want to perform: ");
}

int check_option(int option)
{
    if(option > 0 && option < 7)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int check_size(int size)
{
    if(size > 0 && size <= 100)
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}

void initialize_2Darray(int x[][MAX], int size)
{
    int i, s; //counters
    for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
        for(s=0; s < size; s++) {
            x[i][s] = rand()%10;
        }
    }
}

void print_2Darray(int x[][MAX], int size)
{
    int i, s; //counters
    for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for(s=0; s < size; s++) {
            printf("%d ", x[i][s]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void initialize_1Darray(int y[], int size)
{
    int i, r;
    for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
        r = rand()%10;
        y[i] = r;
    }
}

void print_1Darray(int y[], int size)
{
    int i;
    //Prints array values until (s)ize is reached
    for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", y[i]);
    }
}

int search_min(int x[][MAX], int r, int c, int size)
{
    int i, j; //counters
    int min = 9;
    for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
        if(x[r][i] < min) {
            min = x[r][i];
        }
    }
    for(j=0; j < size; j++) {
        if(x[j][c] < min) {
            min = x[j][c];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int count_match(int x[][MAX], int y[], int size, int r)
{
    int i, j, count;
    for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < size; j++) {
            if(y[i] == x[r][j])
                count++;
        }
    return count;
}

int closest_row(int x[][MAX], int y[], int size)
{
    int l, i, j; //counters
    int sum = 0;
    int dif = 0;
    int row, totaldif; //best matching row & total dif
    for(l=0; l < size; l++) {
        for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
            for(j=0; j < size; j++) {
                dif = abs(y[j] - x[i][j]);
                sum += dif;
            }
            if(sum < totaldif) {
                totaldif = sum;
                row = i;
            }

            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    return row;
}

void sort_1Darray(int y[], int size)
{
    int a, b, temp;
    //Loops through the array, swapping values until in proper order of ascension
    for(a = 0; a < size; a++) {
        for(b = 0; b < size-1; b++) {
            if(y[b] > y[b+1]) {
                temp = y[b+1];
                y[b+1] = y[b];
                y[b] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void sort_2Darray(int x[][MAX], int size)
{
    int a, b, c, temp;
    //Loops through the array, swapping values until in proper order of ascension
    for(c=0; c < size; c++) {
        for(a = 0; a < size; a++) {
            for(b = 0; b < size-1; b++) {
                if(x[a][b] > x[a][b+1]) {
                    temp = x[a][b+1];
                    x[a][b+1] = x[a][b];
                    x[a][b] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code *here*, not on external sites.

Comment: Do not ignore `scanf()`'s return value.

Comment: You need to find where the problem is by bisection.  Place `#if 0` and `#endif` around half the code and see whether the problem is still there.  If so, it's in what is not commented out; if it went, it is probably in the commented out section.  Rinse and repeat until it is obvious what the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

Run your code through `indent`. It can help you find this sort of problem very quickly.

[Here's the output from your code.](http://pastebin.com/AxBtf7c6) As you can see, the problem is caused by a missing brace at the end of `count_match()`:

```
int
count_match(int x[][MAX], int y[], int size, int r)
{
        int             i         , j, count;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                        if (y[i] == x[r][j])
                                count++;
                }
                return count;
        }
 /*** CLOSING BRACE MISSING HERE ***/
        int             closest_row(int x[][MAX], int y[], int size){
                int             l         , i, j;
                              //counters
```

Comment: I think technically the missing brace was from one of the for loops because Idt OP was trying to return `count` after one iteration of the outer loop.